# Oracle SQL add colum with the total grouped by other field

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I have this result

```
ZONE    SITE    BRAND    VALUE
north    a      a_brand1    10
north    a      a_brand2    15
north    a      a_brand3    27
south    b      b_brand1    17
south    b      b_brand2    5
south    b      b_brand3    56
```

Is there any way to add a column wih the sum grouped by zone, and site? like this: Total site a = 10+15+27 = 52 and total site b = 17+5+56 = 78

```
ZONE    SITE    BRAND    VALUE    TOTAL_IN_SITE
north    a      a_brand1    10         52
north    a      a_brand2    15         52
north    a      a_brand3    27         52
south    b      b_brand1    17         78
south    b      b_brand2    5          78
south    b      b_brand3    56         78
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sum` window function.

```
select t.*,sum(val) over(partition by zone,site) 
from tbl t
```

Comment: Nice!. Thanks a lot.